# Schoology API: Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, schoology

I have issue with schoology api auth, successfully got oauth_token,oauth_token_secret, but when i am trying to get access token it says

**The consumer_key "{oauth_token}" token "{oauth_token_secret}" combination does not exist or is not enabled.**

Thanks forwardly!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the right credentials? It's working fine for me. I'm getting my API Credentials from https://app.schoology.com/api. (You can replace `app` with whatever custom subdomain your enterprise has)

If you send some code I can help troubleshoot your code.